# jQuery UI draggable iFrame content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

Basically I have a fixed size IFRAME with `overflow: auto`. The IFRAME displays a given page. What I am trying to acheive is to be able to drag the content of the IFRAME around (so that the content can be navigated without using the scrollbars). Is this possible to do, if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access the iframe page to do this, the scrollbars are not part of the parent page. If you can't change the code there I think it isn't possible.

I tried to put something together. It isn't perfect yet, but it's a start:

```
$(function() { /* drag to scroll */
    var move = $('body');
    var x, y;
    var scroll = false;
    move.mousemove(function(event) {
        if (scroll) {
            move.scrollTop(move.scrollTop() + (y - event.pageY));
            move.scrollLeft(move.scrollLeft() + (x - event.pageX));
        }
        x = event.pageX;
        y = event.pageY;
    });
    move.mousedown(function() { scroll = true; return false; });
    move.mouseup(function() { scroll = false; return false; });
});
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jBdjm/

Answer (score 0):

See if jQuery UI works for you.  There is a draggable functionality, and many other features you'll probably end up wanting too, like resizing.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: Yes I have tried using draggable but it won't let me drag the IFRAME content.

Comment: Try this for an iFrame: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-framedialog

Comment: No, that is not what I am after.